# Why does not dispersion occur at night?

Tags: optics

Light scatters at day so we get dusk and twilight as application of dispersion. But why does not the phenomenon occur at night in case of moon. I think the number of ions in ionosphere decreases at night so scattering occurs less due to less energized particles reflecting colours. And I think the wavelength of light coming is low. So the light coming out of particles is not in our visible range. And the particles of dust are usually less in the air. Please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Light scattering does occur at night, and it has nothing to do with the ionosphere. The full Moon's light "washes out" stars and galaxies below a certain magnitude across the entire sky, much to the frustration of terrestrial astronomers. This is caused by Rayleigh scattering of moonlight from nitrogen and oxygen molecules in the atmosphere. The reason you can't detect it with your eyes is because the Moon is very faint compared to the Sun (as evidenced by the fact that it's dark at night and you can look directly at the Moon), so the scattered light is also much, much fainter.

Comment: Re, "much, much, fainter."  The [apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) of the Sun is approximately -26.7.  The apparent magnitude of a typical full moon is about -12.7.  It's a logarithmic scale:  A difference of 14 orders of magnitude corresponds to a brightness ratio of approximately 398,000:1.

Comment: Additional: Moon can be red as a fire when very low at horizon / when Moon shines, even the night sky isn't black but very dark blue.